# Cannot display result of a function

Tags: javascript, json, spotify

I'm trying to create a site in which, through the Spotify Web API, I display the information of a certain element (Artist, Track, Album, etc ...).
In the function in which I search the song I call another function that should make the request on the more specific information of the song (time, key ....) and return the result to be printed together with the result of the first function.
The problem is that when I go to print the result of the second function it gives me the answer "undefined".
The request for the second function I believe is successful because the console does not give me errors. Can someone help me to understand where the error is?

```
    function ricercaTrack() {         // the first function
  var token = document.getElementById("token").innerHTML;
  var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
  var artist = document.getElementById("artista").value;
  artist = artist.replace(" ", "%20");
  console.log(artist);
  xhr.onreadystatechange = function () {
    if (xhr.readyState == 4 && xhr.status == 200) {
      var response = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);
      var result = '';
      for (var i = 0; i < response.tracks.items.length; i++) {
        console.log(response.tracks.items[i]);
        var specifiche = ricercaSpecifiche(response.tracks.items[i].id);    //the call of the second function

        result += '<div class="border"><div class="card-body">' +
          '<img style="float:right;" src=' + response.tracks.items[i].album.images[2].url + '>' +
          'Nome : ' + response.tracks.items[i].name + '<br/>' +
          'Artista : ' + response.tracks.items[i].artists[0].name + '<br/>' +
          'N° Traccia : ' + response.tracks.items[i].track_number + '<br/>' +
          'Tipologia : ' + response.tracks.items[i].type + '<br/>' +
          specifiche + '<br/>' +
          '<iframe src="https://open.spotify.com/embed?uri=' + response.tracks.items[i].uri + '" width="300" height="80" frameborder="0" allowtransparency="true" allow="encrypted-media"></iframe>' + '</div></div>';
      }
      alert
      document.getElementById("artists").innerHTML = result;
    }
  };
  xhr.open('GET', "https://api.spotify.com/v1/search?q=" + artist + "&type=track&market=IT&limit=10&offset=5", true);
  xhr.setRequestHeader('Accept', 'application/json');
  xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
  xhr.setRequestHeader('Authorization', 'Bearer ' + token);
  xhr.send();
}

function ricercaSpecifiche(i) {       //the second function
  var token = document.getElementById("token").innerHTML;
  var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();

  xhr.onreadystatechange = function () {
    if (xhr.readyState == 4 && xhr.status == 200) {
      var response = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);
      var specifiche = '';
      specifiche +=
        'BPM : ' + response.tempo + '<br/>' +
        'Scala : ' + response.key + '<br/>';
    }    
    return specifiche;
  };
  xhr.open('GET', "https://api.spotify.com/v1/audio-features/"+ i, true);
  xhr.setRequestHeader('Accept', 'application/json');
  xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
  xhr.setRequestHeader('Authorization', 'Bearer ' + token);
  xhr.send();

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing the last parameter to false in this statement inside method `ricercaSpecifiche`

```
xhr.open('GET', "https://api.spotify.com/v1/audio-features/"+ i, false);
```

It will cause this call to be synchronous and `specifiche` variable will have result

**Updated Method:**

```
function ricercaSpecifiche(i) { //the second function
    var token = document.getElementById("token").innerHTML;
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    var specifiche = '';

    xhr.open('GET', "https://api.spotify.com/v1/audio-features/" + i, false);
    xhr.setRequestHeader('Accept', 'application/json');
    xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
    xhr.setRequestHeader('Authorization', 'Bearer ' + token);
    xhr.send();

    if (xhr.status == 200) {
        var response = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);

        specifiche +=
        'BPM : ' + response.tempo + '<br/>' +
        'Scala : ' + response.key + '<br/>';
        return specifiche;

    }
}
```

Comment: thanks for the response, but the result it's the same

Comment: Put `debugger` statement before  `result += '<div...` statement and second debugger statement after ` if (xhr.readyState == 4 && xhr.status == 200) {` inside `ricercaSpecifiche` method and check which one is executed first. Also, ensure that `https://api.spotify.com/v1/audio-features/{id}` api calls are successful using Developer tools network tab.

Comment: I have tried and it is performed before searchSpecifications (), I also tried to insert an alert (specifications) before returning specific and as a message from "BPM: 144.009 <br/> Scale: 10 <br/>" but when it goes to print continuously to give undefined

Comment: I have updated my answer and added the updated `ricercaSpecifiche` method with synchronous call. Check if it works.